# Background image change glitches

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to make a simple level with Pygame, which changes the background, when the player moves to a specific position (a simple level/scene change).

At startup, my first background is drawn correctly. When I change the background (move to the top left corner), the second background gets drawn correctly. But when I move to specific positions on my screen, behind the transparent sprite (set transparent with set_keycolor) not my second (correct) background is drawn, but the initial first one.

Do I heave to explicitly clear the background from the screen object? Do I have to delete the screen object, and create a complete new one?

program.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame

from player import Character

# see if we can load more than standard BMP
if not pygame.image.get_extended():
    raise SystemExit("Sorry, extended image module required")

# globals
id = 1

# main
def main(winstyle=0):
    # Initialize pygame
    pygame.init()

    SCREENRECT = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 630, 450)
    winstyle = 0  # |FULLSCREEN
    bestdepth = pygame.display.mode_ok(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, 32)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, bestdepth)

    BG_TILE_SIZE = 90

    # decorate the game window
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame TEST")
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

    # create the background, tile the bgd image
    background = pygame.Surface(SCREENRECT.size)
    background.fill((0,0,255))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Initialize Game Groups
    all = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()

    # assign default groups to each sprite class
    Character.containers = all

    # Create Some Starting Values
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # initialize our starting sprites
    player = Character(SCREENRECT)

    # Run our main loop whilst the player is alive.
    while player.alive():

        # get input
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return

        # update all the sprites
        all.update()

        # handle player input
        player.move(pygame.key.get_pressed(), SCREENRECT)

        # change background
        indexX, indexY = player.rect.center
        if checkPlayerPosition(indexY, screen, background):
            player.rect = player.image.get_rect(center=SCREENRECT.center)

        # clear/erase the last drawn sprites
        all.clear(screen, background)

        # draw the scene
        dirty = all.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update(dirty)

        # cap the framerate at 60fps. Also called 60HZ or 60 times per second.
        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.time.wait(1000)

# change the background
def checkPlayerPosition(indexY, screen, background):
    global id
    if id == 1:
        if indexY < 90:
            screen.fill((0,0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            background.fill((0,0,255))
            id = -1
            return True
    else:
        if indexY > 360:
            screen.fill((0,0,255))
            pygame.display.flip()
            background.fill((0,0,0))
            id = 1
            return True
    return False

# call the "main" function if running this script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Here's the code for my sprite.

player.py:

```
import os
import pygame

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # fields
    speed = 4
    run = 1
    images = []

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, SCREENRECT):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
        self.setCharImages()
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=SCREENRECT.center)
        self.reloading = 0
        self.origtop = self.rect.top
        self.facing = -1

    # sets the character image array
    def setCharImages(self):
        img = self.load_image("char.png")
        img.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        self.images = [img, 
                       pygame.transform.flip(img, 1, 1),
                       pygame.transform.rotate(img, 270),
                       pygame.transform.rotate(img, 90)]

    # loads an image from disk
    def load_image(self, file):
        try:
            MAIN_DIR = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
            surface = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, "img", file))
        except pygame.error:
            raise SystemExit('Could not load image "%s" %s' % (file, pygame.get_error()))
        return surface.convert()

    # move operation and animation
    def move(self, keystate, SCREENRECT):
        if keystate[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
            self.run = 2
        else:
            self.run = 1

        movX = (keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]) * self.speed * self.run
        movY = (keystate[pygame.K_DOWN] - keystate[pygame.K_UP]) * self.speed * self.run

        self.rect.move_ip(movX, movY)
        self.rect = self.rect.clamp(SCREENRECT)

        if movX < 0:
            self.image = self.images[0]
        elif movX > 0:
            self.image = self.images[1]
        if movY < 0:
            self.image = self.images[2]
        elif movY > 0:
            self.image = self.images[3]
```

Here's the first level, when starting the game.

[image: Level 1]

Here's the glitched version, after I change the level and the background gets black. As you can see, the transparent background of the sprite get's replaced with the first added background layer, not the second one.

[image: Level 2]

So basicaly I'd say, when moving my sprite the wrong background get's redrawn, when it leaves it position. This only happens on the second screen as well! If I move back to the first one, I don't experience this glitch.

So basically the two lines in my short code example above are actually calling this function here. Maybe this causes the problem?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the color of the *Surface* that is used to clear the screen:

> ```py
> all.clear(screen, background)
> ```

You have to `fill` the `background` with a new color and clear the screen with the same color:

```py
def checkPlayerPosition(self, indexX, indexY, screen):
        if self.id == 1:
            if indexX <= 2 and indexY == 0:
                backgrund.fill((0, 0, 0)) 
                screen.blit(backgrund, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                return True
        else:
            if indexX < 3 and indexY == 4:
                backgrund.fill((0, 0, 255)) 
                screen.blit(backgrund, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                return True
        return False
```

Furthermore, call `all.clear(screen, background)` after `checkPlayerPosition`:

```py
while player.alive():

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            return

    all.update()
    player.move(pygame.key.get_pressed(), map.matrix)

    indexX, indexY = player.mapPosition()
    if map.checkPlayerPosition(indexX, indexY, screen):
        player.rect = player.image.get_rect(center=SCREENRECT.center)

    # draw the scene
    all.clear(screen, background)
    dirty = all.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update(dirty)

    # cap the framerate at 60fps. Also called 60HZ or 60 times per second.
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, and your code was very helpful so thanks!

When I tested the answer it all worked fine, but then I tried to implement more of my logic and it failed again. I changed the line:

```
background.fill((0,0,255))
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

to the following:

```
bgGreen = load_image("background_green.png")
background = pygame.Surface(SCREENRECT.size) # <- this was wrong
for height in range(0, 450, 90):
   for width in range(0, 630, 90):
      background.blit(bgGreen, (width, height))
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

I then discovered, that the "glitch" disappeared, when I removed the second line (the Surface constructor call).

So I'd say I totally misunderstood passing of the arguments in Python. The background was passed to the function by value not by reference? And so, I made a new Surface on my background, but when the function returned to my main game loop, it continued with the original background object.

I hope I got my explanation right, and this seems like a really stupid mistake by myself. But I managed to change my initial program, and now everything works fine and as I expected it to do.

@Rabbid76: Thanks for your patience. Should I mark your answer as correct/helpful as well, as it helped me getting the game loop arranged right? And of course it helped me a lot in finding my own bug...